# How whatsApp managed to always receive call notification in Android?

Tags: android, websocket, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, webrtc

I am working on a VOIP calling app based on WebRTC. For the signalling I'm using websocket which is implemented on a background service. But most of the case the service get killed by the OS, so I implemented Firebase Cloud messaging (FCM) to send the Call offer notification which works on most of the device. But it has delay and chinese variant phone doesn't get FCM notification if it is removed from the recent app list. But I have tested WhatsApp on all of these phone and it can able to send call notification almost 100% of the time on any android device. So how whatsapp managed to send and receive those signalling call offer notifications in every case.

Comment: Xiaomi has a whitelist for it's custom battery optimization (which includes WhatsApp, and obviously not our apps)  there's not a lot of things that you can do, but granting all permissions from app details, other permissions and excluding it from battery optimizationa might help. Also starting a foreground service after receiving the FCM push will help a lot

Comment: Many phones have these special whitelists, so the competition with WhatsApp is not fair. When your app achieves a billion daily users, you will be able to negotiate with the manufacturers.